# Retrieving related data with wordpress and advanced custom fields

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I have created a custom Post Type: `reviews` in code and I have created custom field types using [Advanced Custom Fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) plugin.

My custom Post type `reviews` uses a custom field, and one of those fields is a relationship field that relates the `review` to WooCommerce `product` post type.  When I look at a `review` page, I can retrieve the related `product` relationship.

However, when I view the `product` page and try to display it's associated `review` I am having difficulties.

I have looked at Advanced Custom Fields documentation around [bidirectional relationship](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/bidirectional-relationships/), but the documentation differs from what I have on my computer:  I can't see this Advanced tab, so I don't know how to set the 'bidirectional: true` on the relationship field.

So I am now trying to code it in `wordpress/content-single-page`.

I first used

```
          $args = [
            
            'post_type' => 'reviews',
            'meta_query' => [
                'key' => 'related_product',
                'value' => '"' . get_the_ID() . '"'
                ]
            ];
            
          $reviews = get_posts($args);
```

But that returned ALL the reviews.  I only want **a review that relates to the product**.

Using the database I can get the data I need by using this query

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_postmeta` AS M
WHERE M.meta_key = 'related_product'
AND M.meta_value LIKE '%{$productId}%';
```

And that MySQL query returns a `post_id` which will allow me to identify the related `reviews(post_id)` of the product

My question is:

1. Why can't I see the Advanced Tab that would allow me to mark the relational field bidirectional in Advanced Custom Fields? and if I could set the field as bidirectional, would that solve the issue?
2. If I have to write the SQL Query myself to find the related reviews for the product, how can I translate that SQL Query above into code that can be run in PHP?

**** UPDATE *****

Using the `Advanced Custom Field Key` instead of the `Advanced Custom Field Name` in the `get_posts` `meta_query` arguments didn't help.  That query still returns ALL the posts of type `reviews`. I believe for some reason perhaps get_posts is ignoring the meta_query values.

```
$productID = get_the_ID();
    
    $args = [
        'post_type' => 'leirmheasanna',
        'meta_query' => [
            'key' => 'field_64d8fd0dfc04e',
            'value' => $productID 
            ]
        ];
        
    $reviews = get_posts($args);
```

*** UPDATE 2 ****

Using the suggested

```
global $wpdb, $product;

$field_key = 'field_648f2aaff9f4b';

$reviews = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare("
   SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta AS pm
   WHERE pm.meta_key = '%s'
   AND pm.meta_value = %d
   ", $field_key, $post->ID ));
```

returns 0 results. I believe this is because when I look in the database the $product->ID is not the only value stored in that field. So I tried to use 'LIKE' instead of '=' but still no luck.
Below are some screenshots of the different queries, some that work and some that dont.

[image]
[image]

*** UPDATE 3 *****

I finally found the right syntax for the `$wpdb_getresults()` query.

```
    $column = 'related_product';
    $value = '%'.get_the_ID().'%';
    
    
    $reviews = $wpdb->get_results(
        $wpdb->prepare(
            "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta AS pm
            WHERE pm.meta_key = '%s'
            AND pm.meta_value LIKE '%s'
            ", $column, $value));
```

Comment: `'value' => '"' . the_ID() . '"'` - `the_ID` writes directly to the output buffer, so no value actually gets inserted here. You need to use `get_the_ID` if you want to get the ID _returned_, so that you can concatenate it with those text literals.

Comment: Bidirectional is a "Pro" feature, so commercial.

Answer (score 2):

**How to work with ACF meta-key:**

In ACF under Field Group, in the right up corner you have "Screen Options" tab:

**Enable "key" checkbox**

[image]

Then Open/edit the related field group: Now the "key" will appear for "related_product".

[image]

Then use this "key" *(like: `field_648f2aaff9f4b`)* as `meta_key` instead of "related_product" field slug.

So in your code:

```php
global $post;

$reviews = get_posts([
    'post_type' => 'reviews',
    'meta_query' => [
        'key' => 'field_648f2aaff9f4b',
        'value' => $post->ID
    ]
]);
```

Or also:

```php
global $wpdb, $post;

$field_key = 'field_648f2aaff9f4b';

$reviews = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare("
    SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta AS pm
    WHERE pm.meta_key = '%s'
    AND pm.meta_value like %s
", $field_key, "%{$post->ID}%" ));
```

Take care to replace `field_648f2aaff9f4b`with the correct key for "related_product" field. 
It should work.

**Note:** Bidirectional feature is a commercial feature for the "Pro" paid version, that you don't really need, in this case.

Comment: Thanks for this really detailed answer. 

Unfortunately I still haven't got it working. 

Using the key hash 'field_1234455555' instead of the key name didn't work.  The query still returns ALL the posts of type review.  I think for some reason the query is ignoring the meta_query values. 

Then using the prepared db query -> that returns 0 results. I think that may be because the `meta_value` in the db looks like this: `a:1:{i:0;s:5:"10928";)` so I think the statement needs to be LIKE instead of =   but I might be totally off with that.  I know next to nothing about MySQL

Comment: I have updated the $wpdb query. Why you don't use WooCommerce integrated reviews?

Comment: Thanks again so much for your help.  Unfortunately I'm still seeing the same results.   

The `get_posts()` continues to ignore the `meta_query` arguments

and the `$wpdb->get_results()` query is not able to return ANY results.  

I'm not using Woocommerce integrated reviews because that model isn't quite what I need. These reviews are press clippings from media and need more attributes than the integrated woocommerce reviews.  I'm putting it to one side for now. Hopefully it will become clear later why my db queries are not working as expected.

Comment: I finally got it to work. Here's the query that works

`       
        $column = 'related_product';
        $value = '%'.get_the_ID().'%';
        
        
        $reviews = $wpdb->get_results(
            $wpdb->prepare(
                "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta AS pm
                WHERE pm.meta_key = '%s'
                AND pm.meta_value LIKE '%s'
                ", $column, $value));
`